# MSI laptop with amd switchable graphics and ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10

I am new with Ubuntu and I am having problems with getting my laptop work properly with Ubuntu 11.10.
I would like to know, if anyone can help my with my problem, please.

I would like to know if it is possible to turn off the ATI card in the Ubuntu. Because now when I am working with the Ubuntu, my laptops fan is working all the time ant the temperature is getting very high and also the battery runs out very fast so I would like to know how tu turn off the ATI card and use only the intel card.

In the system boot msi doesn't have an option tu tur off the card.

If someone could help me, it would be very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [thread.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450)

Let us know if it worked. Good luck.